# Service Fabric error: "Service does not exist"

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I am getting error `FabricServiceNotFoundException: Service does not exist.` and I can't figure out why. The service name I am creating is exactly what it is deployed in my cluster.

This is the code where I create my service:

```
return ServiceProxy.Create<ICheckoutService>(
                new Uri("fabric:/ECommerce/ECommerce.CheckoutService"),
                new ServicePartitionKey(0));
```

This is the explorer view. The name of the service matches my code. I'm doing it with other services with no problem.

[image]

I tried a complete restart but I got the same error:

1. Deleted application from the cluster
2. Unprovisioned type from the cluster
3. Restarted the cluster
4. Restarted Visual Studio
5. Rebuild and deployed application

### Update

After testing around I found out that the error occurs depending on the order on which I call services through my API methods.

If I deploy the application and call methods `checkout` and `get basket` they give "Service not found" error.

However, if I call other methods first that perform some change (POST), then it works... weird right? This is my repo to help take a look at the code.

https://github.com/epomatti/azure-servicefabric-productcatalog

[image]

Comment: Did you perform any scaling operations recently after which you are seeing this issue?

Comment: @KarishmaTiwari-MSFT I did not. Just created the new service.

Comment: I've run into this before, and SF doesn't often have the best error messages: for me, the interface type wasn't located when the proxy was created due to a mismatch between the client and the service. Ensure your assembly containing the interface is shared and up to date in all projects.

Comment: The other approach that helped me get better error messages in general was to switch visual studio exception settings to "Break When Thrown". Failing quickly allowed access to exceptions and call stacks closer to the actual problem.

Comment: @maf748 updated the question, see if tell you any clue about the problem. I tried your suggestions but nothing yet.

Comment: @EvandroPomatti Is it a local dev cluster?  If so, is it 1 or 5 node?

Comment: @Oliver yes, local dev, and 1 node

Comment: Could you post the partition settings in the manifest and also the class definition for your service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of @maf748 I turned on "Break When Thrown" configuration for all CLR exceptions, and I discovered that the actual exception was not "Service does not exist".

[image]

In my case, I left the following auto-generated method for an Actor service, which was setting my state in a wrong state, and it was later failing in my own code.

All I needed to do was to remove this method that Visual Studio created from my method and it worked properly.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called whenever an actor is activated.
    /// An actor is activated the first time any of its methods are invoked.
    /// </summary>
    protected override Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        ActorEventSource.Current.ActorMessage(this, "Actor activated.");

        // The StateManager is this actor's private state store.
        // Data stored in the StateManager will be replicated for high-availability for actors that use volatile or persisted state storage.
        // Any serializable object can be saved in the StateManager.
        // For more information, see https://aka.ms/servicefabricactorsstateserialization

        return this.StateManager.TryAddStateAsync("count", 0);
    }
```